# File upload aborted in the middle of uploading

Tags: php, ajax, curl

Little brief about how uploading process flow in my team project.

> In client side we call upload service to application server via AJAX. Application server then forward that file to File Server afterward via Curl (file server is private and can only be accessed by application server)

The situation is like this.

> When files were uploading, it's already pass through the application server and reach Fileserver already. But before the data pass back to client side, user click cancel button from client.

How to check from application server, if user abort the request, then call delete to file server if it's already uploaded?

**My solution**

1. If php setting `ignore_user_abort=false`, I can't check if upload cancelled. So I set it to `true` before curl.

   ```
   ini_set('ignore_user_abort', TRUE);
   ```

   ** Btw, `ignore_user_abort=false` still not terminate curl execution immediately even after script call aborted.
2. Set `CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS` to track progress if call aborted or not.

   ```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'callback_progress');
   ```
3. Handle progress

   ```
   $cancelled = false; //cancel flag

   function callback_progress($download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded){

       //Really need this, if not connection_aborted() never be true and curl still running even if script aborted
       print " "; ob_flush (); flush ();

       if(connection_aborted()!= 0){
           if(!$cancelled) $cancelled = true;
           return 0; //to continue script, and handle later
       }
   }
   ```
4. Proceed

   ```
   curl_close($ch); //close curl
   ini_set('ignore_user_abort', FALSE); //set back to false

   //If $cancelled if true, make delete call to file server using the file id 
   if($cancelled && isset($response['id'])) return $this->removeFile($response['id']);
   ```

But, it's not work. `$cancelled` is still false, although it's already true in `callback_progress` function.

Is there a better way for this? I can't find the right solution anywhere in the net for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a case of the `$cancelled` variable and the call to the `removeFile` method not being available as at your progress function's call the part of the script you put it in will **DEFINITELY** have ran before the first call to callback_progress is made.

Try putting the check to see if `$cancelled` and `request['id']` inside the callback_progress. This way the `removeFile` function should run when `$cancelled` is indeed true